# How to have Firefox correctly calculate the width when his child is an img with width:auto? (in a relative position wrapper)

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I'm trying to get a consistent display of my gallery on Firefox and Chrome. But on the first, it's not as intended...

I'm forcing the height of images and letting the width to auto. On both browsers the images are correctly resized... buuut on Firefox the parent element keeps the original width of the image and not the auto calculated one.

This only appear if the parent height is in percent. If I put another unit like vh, it works as intended.

Why Firefox is doing this? Or it's a PEBKAC...

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery {
  position: absolute;
  left: -180px;
  height: 100%; /* if in vh, the bug disapears! */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
}

.item img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>navbar</nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="gallery">
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/640x360">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vwrdf6jx/

On Firefox can see space between images, there is none on Chrome.
Try to resize the result panel vertically to see the buggy behaviour of Firefox.

Note: I need to keep all this flex/relative/absolute machinery...

Comment: Huummmm, I just found that https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1362999 ...
It's not very encouraging.