# SVG does not scale correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, scale, vector-graphics

I have a SVG (simplified for the Question) with the `max-height: 100%;`. I don't know the width of the element (calculated on runtime). I want it to have a aspect ration of 1:1, (In Illustrator it was a square) and in Firefox it works. But in Chrome it is about 4:3.

Images: (First is in Firefox, second Chrome)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JFh3.jpg

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rs1bp420/

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 45%;
  width: 80%;
}

svg {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 0 5px #13ee37;
}

.cls-1 {
  fill: #13ee37;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 974">
  <title>Vector
  </title>
  <path
        class="cls-1"
        d="M853.92,142.13c-194.92-189.7-515.2-189.32-709,0-193.59,189.07-192.73,499.79,0,688.67,193.37,189.5,513.88,191.67,709.05,2.07C1048.62,643.73,1048.76,331.62,853.92,142.13Z"
        transform="translate(0)"
        >
  </path>
</svg>
</div>
```

I want the SVG to be a square in Chrome, because of the border (or the `box-shadow` in my case)

Comment: Instead of setting the height I would use `width:100vh`

Comment: I took the liberty to add the `.container` from your fiddle since it is what causes this issue.

Comment: And that's funny, but I think it's exactly the same core issue as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384394/how-to-have-firefox-correctly-calculate-the-width-when-his-child-is-an-img-with) also posted today (in someone's timezone), even though it's a few years old discrepancy... (and fast-reading, it seems FF behavior would be the wrong one btw).

Answer (score 3):

This is a quirk in how [inline-replaced elements should get resized](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width). You are in a very special and unclear case where the ratio is known and thus the rule should be

> If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the element has an intrinsic ratio but no intrinsic height or width, then the used value of 'width' is undefined in CSS 2.2. However, it is suggested that, if the containing block's width does not itself depend on the replaced element's width, then the used value of 'width' is calculated from the constraint equation used for block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow.

But then, here we are not in *"normal flow"* because your container element has its position set to `absolute`.

In your case, you can replicate FF behavior in Chrome by assigning the `width` and `height` attributes of you `<svg>` so that they are not unknown at parsing anymore and don't default to 300 x 150px in Chrome.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 45%;
  width: 80%;
}

svg {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 0 5px #13ee37;
}

.cls-1 {
  fill: #13ee37;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 974" width="100%" height="100%">
  <title>Vector
  </title>
  <path
    class="cls-1"
    d="M853.92,142.13c-194.92-189.7-515.2-189.32-709,0-193.59,189.07-192.73,499.79,0,688.67,193.37,189.5,513.88,191.67,709.05,2.07C1048.62,643.73,1048.76,331.62,853.92,142.13Z"
    transform="translate(0)"
    >
  </path>
</svg>
</div>
```